# remote install application failed with 12024

Tags: ios, mdm

I am using our MDM server to install an application to a managed device. the command the server sent to device is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>14b4bf63-f259-4e10-b2f3-109f9ad377bf</string>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>InstallApplication</string>
      <key>ManagementFlags</key>
      <integer>0</integer>
      <key>ManifestURL</key>
      <string>https://dev.xxx.xxx/SelfProv/downloads/MDMClient.plist</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The device just response as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>14b4bf63-f259-4e10-b2f3-109f9ad377bf</string>
    <key>ErrorChain</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ErrorCode</key>
            <integer>12024</integer>
            <key>ErrorDomain</key>
            <string>MCMDMErrorDomain</string>
            <key>LocalizedDescription</key>
            <string>无法验证 https://dev.xxx.xxx/SelfProv/downloads/MDMClient.plist 的应用程序清单。</string>
            <key>USEnglishDescription</key>
            <string>The manifest for the app at https://dev.xxx.xxx/SelfProv/downloads/MDMClient.plist could not be validated.</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>ErrorCode</key>
            <integer>-1001</integer>
            <key>ErrorDomain</key>
            <string>NSURLErrorDomain</string>
            <key>LocalizedDescription</key>
            <string>请求超时。</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>ErrorCode</key>
            <integer>-1001</integer>
            <key>ErrorDomain</key>
            <string>kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork</string>
            <key>LocalizedDescription</key>
            <string>请求超时。</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>RejectionReason</key>
    <string>CouldNotVerifyAppID</string>
    <key>Status</key>
    <string>Error</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>d55e39ccd45ec4db20f69d63fd3b42d05dbf8a7b</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am pretty sure the mainfest url are correct, also the ipa file specified in mainifest url are located correctly.

Anybody could help?

Comment: Most likely your manifest has some problems. It says "he manifest for the app at https://dev.xxx.xxx/SelfProv/downloads/MDMClient.plist could not be validated.". Can you post your manifest here?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue already been identified. the server host the manifest file has bad performance so the request timed out. After the server reboot it work well.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me occasionally. It seems something goes wrong at the server end. Just wait a few minutes and try again.